# Can the decline in neuroplasticity be a factor in why older adults stop liking new music?

Tags: music

I am just a science lover not a neuroscientist. My hypothesis is that the decline in neuroplasticity can be a factor in why older adults stop liking new music:

Older adults have less neuroplasticity than younger adults, which means their brains are less able to adapt and change in response to new stimuli. Music is a complex stimulus that involves multiple brain regions and cognitive processes.

One of the sources of pleasure from listening to music is the recognition of patterns and structures in the musical sounds. This recognition involves the activation of the prefrontal cortex. The prefrontal cortex is also one of the brain regions that shows the most decline in neuroplasticity with aging. Therefore, older adults may have more difficulty in recognizing, learning, and appreciating new patterns and structures in new music genres or styles. They may also have less motivation to seek out new musical experiences, as they may find them less rewarding or enjoyable.

Hence, the hypothesis is that the decline in neuroplasticity in the prefrontal cortex of older adults reduces their ability and willingness to process and enjoy new music.

What could be wrong with my hypothesis? I can't find much answer on the internet so I am asking here.

Comment: How would you approach testing this hypothesis?

Comment: I think that older folks generally adapt less well to novelty in general (hunch only). However, in terms of music you would need to gather evidence that they appreciate new music less than younger people (the *if*); if that is the case, you can start to worry about the *why*. Do you have evidence this is even the case? If yes, more factors play a role; Older folks have different life styles than younger folks, and I reckon they find themselves less often in situations where they encounter new music; they spend more time at work a lot, have kids and seek out other activities.